# How to specify multiple conditions that can be subsetted on jointly or separately in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to be able to define an object that specifies multiple rules. My desired behaviour is that when I use that object in a call to `subset()` it should apply all of the rules, but that I should also be able to pick them out for separate application.

Some sample data:

```
temp_data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0),
                        b = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        c = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                        d = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,0),
                        e = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2))
```

Subsetting, according to some rules:

```
# Rule 1
subset(temp_data, b == 1)
# Rule 2
subset(temp_data, c == 1)
# Rule 3
subset(temp_data, d != 0 & e != 0)
# All three rules
subset(temp_data, b == 1 & c == 1 & d != 0 & e != 0)
```

I have tried collecting the rules together using `expression()`:

```
temp_subset_rules_1 <- expression(b == 1,
                                  c == 1,
                                  d != 0 & e != 0)
```

This runs, but doesn't apply all three rules. It just applies the last one.

```
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_1))
```

I can run each rule separately:

```
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_1[1]))
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_1[2]))
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_1[3]))
```

I can manually run all the rules together:

```
subset(temp_data, 
       eval(temp_subset_rules_1[1]) &
         eval(temp_subset_rules_1[2]) &
         eval(temp_subset_rules_1[3]))
```

I have also tried collecting the rules using `c()` and `quote()`:

```
temp_subset_rules_2 <- c(quote(b == 1),
                         quote(c == 1),
                         quote(d != 0 & e != 0))
```

This doesn't runs at all:

```
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_2))
```

Referencing each rule stored in this way requires `[[` rather than `[`. So this works separately:

```
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[1]]))
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[2]]))
subset(temp_data, eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[3]]))
```

And this works together:

```
subset(temp_data, 
       eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[1]]) &
         eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[2]]) &
         eval(temp_subset_rules_2[[3]]))
```

I am looking for an object that, when passed as the second (`subset =`) argument to `subset()`, will apply all of its components, but where it remains possible to run each rule separately. I.e., the output of these should be the same:

```
subset(temp_data, rules_collected_somehow)
subset(temp_data, b == 1 & c == 1 & d != 0 & e != 0)
```

But also I should be able to extract elements from `rules_collected_somehow` programmatically and be able to produce separately results equal to each of these:

```
subset(temp_data, b == 1)
subset(temp_data, c == 1)
subset(temp_data, d != 0 & e != 0)
```

I had considered the possibility of storing the separate rules as a single rule and then splitting it at the `&`s. But unfortunately that doesn't work because I need some composite rules that have to contain `&` within them.

---

I am aware of (though admittedly don't fully grok) the warning to avoid `subset()` in favour of, for example, `[`. However, I will sometimes be applying this to `survey.design` objects (`survey::svydesign()`), where my understanding is that `subset()` is the approved / preferred function.

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse methods, you can create a list of expressions, and then use `filter()` to apply them all or one at a time.

```r
library(tidyverse)

rule_exprs <- rlang::exprs(b == 1, c == 1, d != 0 & e != 0)

temp_data %>% filter(!!!rule_exprs)
  a b c d e
1 6 1 1 2 1
2 7 1 1 2 1
3 8 1 1 2 1

temp_data %>% filter(!!rule_exprs[[1]])
  a b c d e
1 4 1 0 1 1
2 5 1 0 1 1
3 6 1 1 2 1
4 7 1 1 2 1
5 8 1 1 2 1
6 9 1 1 2 0
7 0 1 1 0 2
```

Comment: This looks nice. Won't work for me, I think, because of the requirement on using `subset()` for `survey.design` objects sometimes. But still appreciate the idea, and can see it working in other situations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your conditions in an expression collection

```
temp_subset_rules_1 <- expression(b == 1,
                                  c == 1,
                                  d != 0 & e != 0)
```

You can write a helper function to join multiple terms into one combining them with `&`

```
join_terms <- function(x) {
  Reduce(function(a, b) bquote((.(a)) & (.(b))), x)
}
```

Then you can use this with `subset/eval`

```
subset(temp_data, eval(join_terms(temp_subset_rules_1)))
subset(temp_data, eval(join_terms(temp_subset_rules_1[2])))
subset(temp_data, eval(join_terms(temp_subset_rules_1[c(1,3)])))
```

Comment: This certainly looks like it would work with my toy example. I'll have a look and see if I can get it working in my actual situation too. (Of course, that might flag up a way in which I've over-abstracted my problem in pursuit of a clear example...!) Thanks.